# What is meant by soaking time in heat treatment?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, metallurgy, metals, heat-treatment

After heating at 950°C and holding the temperature for 3 hours there is a soaking time that is provided for 12 hours. What is the soaking time being referred to here? A detailed reply to this will be very welcome.

Comment: https://www.kloecknermetals.com/blog/the-three-stages-of-heat-treatment/

Comment: It helps to know what is being heat treated here. Otherwise you'll get misunderstandings 
 based on guesswork.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At that high temperature , there are some things like carbides and intermetallics going into solid solution. Also some chemical homogenization ( which is similar to the solution). To a small degree the temperature is becoming more uniform ; although the surface has reached temperature the core of a thick component takes longer to reach temperature ; Usually addressed by typical ASME requirement by " one hour per inch of thickness".  For a lower temperature like 500 C ,it would be time for stress relieving to develop , as in  PWHT. That high temperature sounds like a solution anneal for a ferrous superalloy, followed by a fast cool. However 3 + 12 hours is exceptionally long in my experience.

Comment: Tip: You can also use HTML entities `&Omega;`, `&mu;`, `&deg;`, `&times;`, etc. as well as `<sup>...</sup>` and `<sub>...</sub>` in the posts (but they don't work in the comments).